# tomcat resource missing, servlet not running

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MyServlet implements Servlet
{

    public void init(ServletConfig con) {}

    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res) throws IOException,ServletException
    {

    res.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
    String s="blah";
    String s1="blah";
    out.println("<html><body>");

    if((s.equals(req.getParameter("firstname")))&&(s1.equals(req.getParameter("pwd"))))

    out.println("passwords match");

    else
    out.println("password and name combo does not match");

    out.println("</body></html>");
    }

    public void destroy() {}

    public ServletConfig getServletConfig() { return null;}
    public String getServletInfo() { return null;}
}
```

this is my java file with the servlet class.its saved with the name MyServlet.java and so is the class file.

and here is the xml file:

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>demoo</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>demoo</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/demo</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

i have made the folder as WEB-INF and then classes...
WEB-INF also contains the .xml file

but when i try to run the servlet , it says resource not found
**ps- i am already looking for the servlet with the name :demo**

*localhost:8081/s1/demo**
s1 is the war file
*

> a html file in the war file seems to run fine on the server though.

*

Comment: Please post the url you are trying to access.

Comment: Make sure you compile your class into the folder `WEB-INF/classes`

Comment: they are compiled in the classes folder only .

Comment: Have you deployed your application? in other words is tomcat aware of it? does it say on start up context `s1` was loaded?

Comment: yes.and tomcat also says :true

Comment: are you sure your servlet in the default package ? do you have a package declaration in your servlet class (package ... ;) ?

Comment: yes , the servlet is in the default package, and no , there is no package declaration in my servlet.it was created and compiled in the classes folder only

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 6, just add following annotation in your servlet class and remove the `web.xml` file from the `WEB-INF` directory. I hope it will work

```
@WebServlet(name = "MyServlet", urlPatterns = {"/demo"})
```

Comment: should i add it to the .java file and recompile?

Comment: like this
@WebServlet(name = "MyServlet", urlPatterns = {"/my"})
public class MyServlet implements Servlet {

Answer (score 1):

Use following code, delete your web.xml, recompile and deploy your web app

```
  import javax.servlet.*;
  import java.io.*;
  import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

   @WebServlet(name = "MyServlet", urlPatterns = {"/demo"})
   public class MyServlet implements Servlet {

   public void init(ServletConfig con) {
   }

    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res) throws IOException,    ServletException {

       res.setContentType("text/html");
       PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
       String s = "blah";
       String s1 = "blah";
       out.println("<html><body>");

       if ((s.equals(req.getParameter("firstname"))) && (s1.equals(req.getParameter("lastname")))) {
        out.println("passwords match");
    } else {
        out.println("password and name combo does not match");
    }

    out.println("</body></html>");
}

public void destroy() {
}

public ServletConfig getServletConfig() {
    return null;
}

public String getServletInfo() {
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: gave me an error while compiling the same last night, will give it another go

Comment: umm..compiled this time...but still the same error ...resource not found..urghhh

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven for your project then local application start may be done like that:

```
mvn clean tomcat:run-war
```

Don't forget to mention in your pom.xml

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```